# CSS/HTML5 - Sticky Footers not Working

Tags: html, css, sticky

OK - I admit I am a CSS Newb (be gentle please) and not all that much of an HTML guru either - I am much better with business logic than front ends.  That said, I am developing a web site for my husband (We cant afford to have it done outside).  I am trying to implement a sticky footer on a page that may have variable length.  The problem is that ever since I implemented the menus on the left side of the page, the footers jump up to the top of the page.  I have no idea why, and can't seem to figure out why.  The page contents are pulled from a database.  The basic HTML layout is written in HTML with the detail information (the tab strips, menus, content) written out of a database via php.  The basic HTML structure is like this:

```
<body>
    <div id='content-container'>
         <div id='wrapper'>...</div>
         <div id='body-wrapper'>
             <div id='floater-wrapper'>
                  <div id='floating-menu-1'>
                  </div>
                  <div id='floating-menu-2'>
                  </div>
             <div>
             <div id='content'>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div id='foot-wrapper'>
               <div id='foot-content'>
               </div>
          </div>
 </body>
```

The CSS is as follows (Note:  I have tried all variations of the sticky footers solution that I have found here and on line.)  Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
<style>
/*START NAV*/
ul, ul li, li{list-style: none;}
#navigation-wrapper{
    background-image: url(images/line.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: right bottom; 
    height: 100px; 
    width: 1000px; 
    margin: 27px 0 0;
    }
#logo{
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    height: 150px; 
    width: 200px; 
    display: block; 
    text-indent: -999993px; 
    background-image: url(images/wgclogo2_small.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center center;
}
#logo a {
    margin: 10px 0 0; 
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#navigation{
    display: block; 
    float: right; 
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
#navigation ul {
    color: #323131; 
    font-family: "proxima-nova",sans-serif; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    text-align: right;
}
#navigation li {
    display:inline; 
    padding: 0 0 0 15px; 
    font-weight: 600;
}
#navigation a {
    color: #323131; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-size:13px;
}
#navigation a:hover{
    color: #78756f;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #323131; 
    border-top: 5px solid #323131; 
    padding-top: 12px; 
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
div#nav{
    width: 577px;
    height: 44px;
}
div#nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
div#nav ul li {
    float: right;
}
div#nav ul li a {
    text-indent: 100px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    display: block; 
    height: 44px;
}

/*Start First item in Nav 42+0=42 */
div#nav ul li.about a {width: 42px}
div#nav ul li.about a:hover, div#nav ul li.about a.current { }
/*End First item in Nav*/

/*Start Next item in Nav 58+42=100 */
div#nav ul li.food a {width: 58px}
div#nav ul li.food a:hover, div#nav ul li.food a.current { }
/*End Next item in Nav*/

/*Start Next item in Nav 54+100=154 */
div#nav ul li.special a {width: 54px}
div#nav ul li.special a:hover, div#nav ul li.special a.current { }
/*End Next item in Nav*/

/*Start Next item in Nav 42+154=196 */
div#nav ul li.service a {width: 42px}
div#nav ul li.service a:hover, div#nav ul li.service a.current { }
/*End Next item in Nav*/

/*Start Next item in Nav No more adding neccesary*/
div#nav ul li.cost a {width: 52px}
div#nav ul li.cost a:hover, div#nav ul li.cost a.current { }
/*End Next item in Nav*/

/*Start Next item in Nav No more adding neccesary*/
div#nav ul li.contact a {width: 57px}
div#nav ul li.contact a:hover, div#nav ul li.contact a.current { }
/*End Next item in Nav*/

/*Start Next item in Nav No more adding neccesary*/
div#nav ul li.customers a {width: 50px}
div#nav ul li.customers a:hover, div#nav ul li.customers a.current { }
/*End Next item in Nav*/
/*END NAV*/
/*START CONTENT & HEADERS*/
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/bkg.png); 
}
#content-container{
    min-height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: top;    
}

#body-wrapper{
/*  overflow: auto; */
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;  
    vertical-align: top;

}
#content{
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width:800px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
h1 {
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #003366;
    font: normal normal 30px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h2 {
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #993300;
    font: 24px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    margin-bottom: 10px;    
}

h3 {
    text-align: left;
    font: 16px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #666666;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
p.alert{
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font: 12px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #ff5600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#content ul, ol {
    border-left: 3px solid #dfedcb;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #323131;
    font: 16px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

/* START Floating Menu Styles */
#floater-container{
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute; 
    left: 0px; 
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: start;
}
div.floating-menu {
    position:static;
    background:rgba(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25);
    border:1px solid #299366;
    width:185px;
    z-index:300;
}
div.floating-menu a, div.floating-menu h3 {display:block;margin:0 0.5em;}

/*END Floaters */



/*END CONTENT & HEADERS*/

/*START LOGIN*/
#login-wrapper{ vertical-align:  middle; border-style: solid; border-width: thin; height: 125px; width: 500px; margin: 27px 0 0;}
#facebook{text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background-image: url(images/login_border.png); background-position: right center; background-repeat: no-repeat; display:inline-block ; float: left; width: 200px; height: 125px; margin: 0 0 0 0;}
#local_login{vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; float: right; width: 300px; height: 125px; margin: 0 0 0 0;}
/*END LOGIN*/
/* START TABSTRIP STYLES */

.tabStrip ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.tabStrip li {
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
}
.tabLink {
    display: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #e8e8e8;
    border: #dadada solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
    color: #8a8a8a;
}
.tabLinkActive {
    display: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    border: #c0c0c0 solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
    color: #0066ff;
}
.tabContent {
    display: none;
}
.tabContentActive {
    display: inherit;
    clear: both;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px #dedede solid;
    padding: 10px;
/*  height:inherit; */
    width:97.5%;
}
/*END TABSTRIPS */


</style>
```

Comment: Your markup is not even working for me?

Comment: I'm getting a blank page

Comment: I didn't post any content just the div structure.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` before `#content` should be `</div>` and you missing one closing `</div>` before `</body>`.

```
<body>
<div id='content-container'>
     <div id='wrapper'>...</div>
     <div id='body-wrapper'>
         <div id='floater-wrapper'>
              <div id='floating-menu-1'>
              </div>
              <div id='floating-menu-2'>
              </div>
         </div>
         <div id='content'>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id='foot-wrapper'>
           <div id='foot-content'>
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

But aside from that you are using absolute positioning for `#content` and `#body-wrapper`. Absolute positioning is causing those blocks to be rendered, lets say, on a different layer, so anything that goes after absolute positioned will not be rendered below those block but below the previous block that has `position` set to `relative`.

The only solution I ever come up with for sticking footer to the bottom of the page is by using javascript. After page is loaded you check whether page main content is big enough to place footer at the bottom. If not, you set the height of the appropriate element to make it so.

Comment: GENIUS!  We have a winner!  Thanks!  I had noticed the layers thing and was trying to figure out why it kept rendering that way.  I had tried playing with the z-axis and nothing. Oh and the Div thing was my type-o when posting my code snippet in here.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
/* IE 6 and down:
#container {
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I have done that in about 10 different variations over the past two days - it has absolutely no effect.  I think there is something to do with the multiple divs in the container above it.  I have also tried moving the footers in and out a level in the div structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one prepared

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

List of supported browsers.

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/browser-list.html

Comment: Tha answer above, with the position answered the question.